# How to deploy a maven artifact on the CLI with a interactive UID and password?

Tags: maven

Maven doesn't have a great way to dynamically prompt for a UID / Password during a;

```
mvn deploy
```

command;

@Adligo

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using the following deploy.sh bash script;

```
#!/bin/bash
#Expand new lines \n
shopt -s xpg_echo


# Thanks https://medium.com/@Drew_Stokes/bash-argument-parsing-54f3b81a6a8f
while (( "$#" )); do
  case "$1" in
    -a | --artifactory_server)   artServer="$2" ; shift 2  ;;
    -b | --bearer_token) oauthToken="$2" ; shift 2  ;;
    -d | --debug)   debug=1 ; shift 1  ;;
    -e | --oauth_server) oauthServer="$2" ; shift 2  ;;
    -g | --group_path) groupPath="$2" ; shift 2  ;;
    -l | --load_properties) loadProperties="y" ; shift 1  ;;
    -m | --retry_seconds)   retrySecs="$2" ; shift 2  ;;
    -n | --gen-token-opts) genTokenOpts="$2" ; shift 2  ;;
    -o | --oauth_uid) oauthUid="$2" ; shift 2  ;;
    -p | --password)   password="$2" ; shift 2  ;;
    -r | --retrys)   retrys="$2" ; shift 2  ;;
    -s | --oauth_password) oauthPass="$2" ; shift 2  ;;
    -t | --auth_type)   authType="$2" ; shift 2  ;;
    -u | --uid)   uid="$2" ; shift 2  ;;
    -v | --version)   version="$2" ; shift 2  ;;
    -*|--*=) # unsupported flags
      echo "Error: Unsupported flag $1" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    *) # preserve positional arguments
      PARAMS="$PARAMS $1"
      shift
      ;;
  esac
done

if [[ "y" == "$loadProperties" ]]; then
  echo "loading defaults from deployProperties.sh "
  . ./deployProperties.sh
fi

# Overwrite the cli options using the values in ./deployProperties.sh when not present
# Alphabetized
if [[ -z $artServer ]]; then 
  artServer=$ART_SERVER
fi

if [[ -z $authType ]]; then 
  authType=$AUTH_TYPE
fi

if [[ -z $debug ]]; then 
  debug=$DEBUG
fi

if [[ -z $oauthPass ]]; then 
  oauthPass=$OAUTH_PASS
fi

if [[ -z $oauthServer ]]; then 
  oauthServer=$OAUTH_SERVER
fi

if [[ -z $oauthToken ]]; then 
  oauthToken=$OAUTH_TOKEN
elif [[ "none" == $oauthToken ]]; then
  oauthToken=""
fi

if [[ -z $oauthUid ]]; then 
  oauthUid=$OAUTH_UID
fi

if [[ -z $genTokenOpts ]]; then
  genTokenOpts=$GENERATE_TOKEN_OPTS
fi

if [[ -z $groupPath ]]; then 
  groupPath=$GROUP_PATH
fi

if [[ -z $password ]]; then 
  password=$PASSWORD
fi

if [[ -z $retrys ]]; then 
  retrys=$RETRYS
fi

if [[ -z retrySecs ]]; then 
  retrySecs=$RETRY_SECS
fi

if [[ -z $version ]]; then 
  version=$VERSION
fi

if [[ -z $uid ]]; then 
  uid=$UID
fi

#Begin Logic
if [[ "$debug" = "1" ]]; then
  echo "executing with parameters\n"
  echo "artServer=$artServer"
  echo "authType=$authType"
  echo "debug=$debug"
  echo "oauthPass=$oauthPass"
  echo "oauthToken=$OoauthToken"
  echo "oauthUid=$oauthUid"
  echo "groupPath=$groupPath"
  echo "password=$password"
  echo "retrys=$retrys"
  echo "retrySecs=$retrySecs"
  echo "password=$password"
  echo "uid=$uid"
  echo "version=$version"
fi
if [[ -z $version ]]; then
  echo No Version, exiting
  exit 1
fi

function exec {
    
  if [[ "$debug" = "1" ]]; then
    echo "executing\n$1"
  fi
  status=$?
  eval $1
  status=$?
  times=$(($retrys))
  if [[ $times -lt 1 ]]; then
    times=$((1))
  fi
  sleepTime=$(($retrySecs))
  if [[ sleepTime -lt 1 ]]; then
    sleepTime=$((10))
  fi  
  count=$((1))
  while [ $count -lt $times ]
  do
    echo "count is $count"
    if [[ $status == 0 ]]; then
      echo "command sucessful"
      return 0
    else
      echo "Waiting $sleepTime seconds ..."
      sleep $sleepTime
      eval $1
      status=$?
      count=$(($count+1))
    fi
  done
  
}

jar=`ls target | grep jar`

echo Deploying the following to ART_SERVER is 
echo $artServer
echo $jar

if [[ -f "pom.xml" ]]; then
  echo "Found pom.xml file!"
else
  echo "There is NO pom.xml file exiting;"
  exit 0;
fi

if [[ "simple" = "$authType" ]]; then 
  if [[ -z $password ]]; then
    read -s -p "Password: " password
  fi
  retrys=$(($retrys))
  if [[ $retrys -le 1 ]]; then
    echo "retrys are -le 1 running\ncurl -u $artUid:$password -X PUT \"$artServer/$groupPath/$version/$jar\" -T target/$jar"
    curl -u $artUid:$password -X PUT "$artServer/$groupPath/$version/$jar" -T target/$jar
    echo "retrys are -le 1 running\ncurl -u $artUid:$password -X PUT \"$artServer/$groupPath/$version/pom.xml\" -T pom.xml"
    curl -u $artUid:$password -X PUT "$artServer/$groupPath/$version/pom.xml" -T pom.xml
  else
    exec "curl -u $artUid:$password -X PUT \"$artServer/$groupPath/$version/$jar\" -T target/$jar"
    exec "curl -u $artUid:$password -X PUT \"$artServer/$groupPath/$version/pom.xml\" -T pom.xml"
  fi
  # note md5 checksums are hidden by default 
  # https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-show-the-checksum-files-when-browsing-artifacts-from-the-direct-url/
elif [[ "oauth" = "$authType" ]]; then 
  if [[ -z $oauthUid ]]; then
    read -p "OAuth User Id: " oauthUid
  fi
  
  if [[ -z $oauthToken ]]; then
    if [[ -z $oauthPass ]]; then
      read -s -p "OAuth Password: " oauthPass
    fi
    
    status=$?
    cmd="curl -XPOST $oauthServer $generateTokenOpts --data-urlencode \"username=$oauthUid\"  --data-urlencode \"password=$oauthPass\""
    status=$?
    if [[ "0" == "$status" ]]; then
      echo "Unable to contatct the following server, is it down?"
      echo "$oauthServer"
      exit 0;
    fi
    oauthResponce=`eval $cmd`
    if [[ "$DEBUG" = "1" ]]; then
      echo "\n\oauthResponce\n$oauthResponce"
      echo "\n\n\n parsing token"
    fi
    oauthToken=`echo $oauthResponce | sed "s/{.*\"access_token\":\"\([^\"]*\).*}/\1/g"`
    echo "\n\n\nGot the following token;"
    echo $oauthToken
  else
    echo "Using provided oauthToken"
  fi
  retrys=$(($retrys))
  if [[ $retrys -le 1 ]]; then
    echo "retrys are -le 1 running\ncurl -u $oauthUid:$oauthToken -X PUT \"$artServer/$groupPath/$version/$jar\" -T target/$jar"
    curl -u $oauthUid:$oauthToken -X PUT "$artServer/$groupPath/$version/$jar" -T target/$jar
    echo "retrys are -le 1 running\ncurl -u $oauthUid:$oauthToken -X PUT \"$artServer/$groupPath/$version/pom.xml\" -T pom.xml"
    curl -u $oauthUid:$oauthToken -X PUT "$artServer/$groupPath/$version/pom.xml" -T pom.xml
  else
    exec "curl -u $oauthUid:$oauthToken -X PUT \"$artServer/$groupPath/$version/$jar\" -T target/$jar"
    exec "curl -u $oauthUid:$oauthToken -X PUT \"$artServer/$groupPath/$version/pom.xml\" -T pom.xml"
  fi
else
  echo "Unknown AUTH_TYPE must be one of (simple, oauth)"  
fi
```

And a deployProperties.sh file like;

```
# ART short for Artifactory
ART_SERVER=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local
#
# Try to keep this out of this file and use it from the
# CLI dialog which is a bit more secure :)
#
ART_PASSWORD=
#
# This is the uid of the ART_SERVER
#
ART_UID=admin

#
# This is either simple or oauth (for OAuth bearer tokens)
#
AUTH_TYPE=simple
# 0 is off 1 is on
DEBUG=0

GENERATE_TOKEN_OPTS=`echo -d "instance=maven"`

GROUP_PATH=
RETRYS=3
RETRY_SECS=10
#
# It is NOT recommend to use this setting, as it is less secure
# than the OAUTH_TOKEN setting
#
OAUTH_PASS=
#
# This token MAY be created by this script and copied into this file
# NOTE there is NO option for a OAUTH_PASSWORD which is an intentional security feature
# use the CLI to dialog for the OAuth password
#
OAUTH_TOKEN=
OAUTH_SERVER=
#
# The User Identifier of the OAuth requests
#
OAUTH_UID=
VERSION=
export ART_SERVER ART_PASSWORD ART_UID AUTH_TYPE GENERATE_TOKEN_OPTS RETRYS RETRY_SECS OAUTH_PASS OAUTH_TOKEN OAUTH_SERVER OAUTH_UID TOKEN VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now hosted here;
https://github.com/adligo/artifactory_deploy.sh.adligo.org
Please contribute and allow shorter answers to be posted to stack overflow :)